# Deploy contract - have total supply but no token holder and balance

Tags: solidity, web3js, etherscan

I deploy my contract to etherscan (rinkedby and etherscan). I have my total supply set but i can't see any in in network after deploy.

I even copy the contract ceration code exactly from this contract address to deploy but it does not work: [Contract code here](https://etherscan.io/address/0xf8e06e4e4a80287fdca5b02dccecaa9d0954840f#code). And from several ICO contract address that is live too. (including those with event Transfer to transfer token to owner)

Can anyone verify that is this a code/deployment problem or etherscan testnet problem?

Note: Similar question asked in [this stackoverflow post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/53033/tokens-were-created-but-0-holder-addresses-where-are-tokens)
This is another [link](https://etherscan.io/address/0xead3a6ea1128825005ef5bafeb1626c226ad108c#code) to smart contract that shows the same thing

sample code:

```
function Token(address _crowdSaleAddress) public {

        locked = true;  // Lock the Crowdsale function during the crowdsale
        totalSupply = 300000000e18; 
        name = "TGAME"; // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol = "TGAME"; // Set the symbol for display purposes
        decimals = 18; // Amount of decimals for display purposes
        crowdSaleAddress = _crowdSaleAddress;                             
        balances[crowdSaleAddress] = totalSupply;
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean that when you get the balance of crowdSaleAddress it returns 0?

Comment: @vhie yes it shows 0 and erc20 token owner also shows 0

Comment: How do you invoke the method that returns the balance?

Comment: Can you share github repo and your deployment method. Your question is not self-explanatory for most here. Please, ask for help with a well-defined problem

Comment: What is the link to your contract on the testnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contract works as expected. It is simply an etherscan indexing issue that prevents the information from showing.

If you look up the balance of `0x40bd749d975349e6aaf310007d3ee00bcef5ebdd` using the `balanceOf` function on Etherscan's read contract page, you will get `1000000000000000000000000` as expected.

Etherscan's token info page is largely based on the events emitted by your contract. If you add `emit  Transfer(0x0, msg.sender, totalSupply);` to the end of your constructor, etherscan will be able to detect the single owner as a token holder.

Alternatively, if you want to force it to detect this without redeploying, just send the entire token balance from the owner to itself. This will register a transfer event as well.